# How to find the local instaces using SQLSERVER SMO?

Tags: c#, sql-server

is there is any way to find out the local instaces installed in a single physical machine.

scenario:

Suppose i have installed sqlserevr2005 and sqlexpress on same machine.is there any way to find these instances using SMO..

and i have installed the datafiles of two instaces in different locations.

how to find these datafiles location both at a time

output should be like:

### Sqlinstances:

```
 sqlravikiran
 sqlravikiran\express
```

### files:

D:\datafiles\master.mdf(sqlserver)
 f:\datafiles\master.mdf(sqlexpress)

how to do this

Comment: Almost duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751789/how-to-finding-out-where-sqlserver-databases-installed-using-sqlsmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [nice article in MSDNMAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163409.aspx) and here [the intro page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162202(SQL.90).aspx).

But please try to update and improve your question instead of posting a new and only slightly different one.